# When running an application under ruby 2.3.1 using the rails server command, the following error occurs: can not modify a frozen array (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby, modifier

I have to run an application developed in Ruby on rails. ruby 2.3.1 and rails 4.2.0

When I execute the rails server command. I get the following error:
.... config / initializers / doorkeeper.rb: 75: in `<top (required)>`: can not modify a frozen array (RuntimeError).

Can I explain how to succeed to no longer have this error, thank you

Info : 
The "bundle install" command runs successfully.

The code around doorkeepee.rb near line 75 : Doorkeeper.configuration.token_grant_types << "password"

I'm trying to understand how RAIL_ENV works. Can you help me at the same time?

Comment: did you run `bundle install` ?

Comment: Can you paste in the code around doorkeepee.rb near line 75 and anywhere related variables are defined or modified?

Comment: This is a common problem, you could check whether `bundle install` have run successfully yet, or are you running with the correct `RAILS_ENV`